# Htaccess rewrite rules trouble

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having troubles getting my rewrite rules to work correctly..

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^companies/
RewriteRule ^companies\/\?(.*)([A-Za-z]+) index.php?cpy=$1 [R=301,L,NC] 

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?cid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

The rewrite rules for
domain.com/123
domain.com/abc
seem to work ok,

but the other one I cannot get to work is 
domain.com/companies/?list=this

It seems that apache doesn't find a match for

```
RewriteRule ^companies\/\?(.*)([A-Za-z]+) index.php?cpy=$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with that rule? or if it is something else?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule`s do not match on query strings as a rule.

You can match on them using `RewriteCond` with the parameterized matches appearing as `%1, %2`, etc.

eg.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)([A-Za-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^companies\/ index.php?cpy=%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did not know that, and as you can imagine it makes all the difference in the world when you are trying to find a match.  The code I ended up using (that works great) is                         RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)([A-Za-z]+)
RewriteRule ^companies\/ /index.php?cpy=%1%2 [L]

Comment: @kris: I have been using `mod_rewrite` for years and only found this out relatively recently; the documentation certainly does not stress it.  Glad you are sorted, case closed?